# Where can arbitrary code be placed in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I'm facing confusion due to the different purposes of numerous folders in Nuxt 3. I want to store a simple food list array in a JavaScript file and export it, but I'm uncertain about the appropriate location to place this file.

This is my food.js file:

```js
export const food = ['apple', 'banana', 'some random fruit']
```

Typically, if I'm not using Nuxt 3, I would place the `food.js` file next to the component that will utilize it, like this:

1. `components/myFolder1/FoodView.vue`
2. `components/myFolder1/food.js`

However, in Nuxt 3, this approach is no longer feasible as my `food.js` file will be automatically registered as a component due to Nuxt 3's mechanisms.

Placing `food.js` in the `composables/` folder doesn't make sense since it's just a static file.

Although putting `food.js` in the `utils/` folder seems reasonable, the `utils/` folder doesn't scan nested folders for auto-registration. For instance:

If my `utils/` folder looks like this:

1. `utils/formatDate.js`
2. `utils/foodApp/food.js`

Nuxt 3 will only auto-import `formatDate.js` and ignore `food.js`. I would have to manually import `food.js`, which deviates from Nuxt 3 conventions and potentially complicates the project's comprehension. Additionally, the `utils/` folder isn't an ideal place to store this type of arbitrary code.

Hence, I'm seeking advice on the best location to store such arbitrary code in Nuxt 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt's inability to scan `/utils` subfolders can be bypassed in two ways.

You can create file `/utils/index.js` and re-export features from subfolders you want to use accross the app:

```
// index.js
export { food } from './foodApp/food.js'
```

This is what [Nuxt docs recommend](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/composables#how-files-are-scanned).

The second option is to manually define folders for auto-import inside `defineNuxtConfig`:

```
imports: {
  dirs: [
    'utils/**'
  ]
}
```

You might even be able to auto-import fully arbitrary folder, but I haven't tried this yet.

Last but not least - there is absolutely no problem with creating your own folder of any name. The only issue is that you'll have to deal with manual imports (or play with the config). And there is a little potential future risk that Nuxt will add some more dedicated folders and yours will clash with that.

For example on my work project I just introduced folder `/types` for holding type definitions from backend microservices we generate via OpenAPI.